Magento 2 : Many 404 URL from one product
I'm not sure how this happened, but while doing an audit of our site I noticed we have over 92 404 errors and they all are from the same product. Most of the paths are strange as I never added this product to any of these category pages. Does anyone know what could have caused this in Magento 2.3?
Also, what would be the best way to fix this without having to create 92 URL rewrites?


Have you try to run re-indexing command ?

@Randy
Hey,
Run indexing and flush the cache. If the issue still persists, you can truncate url_rewrite table of entity_type product (Only if you have issue with products URL) and regenerate them by using third party module.
Thank You!

In this situation, You can remove all URLs of this product.
Then you can use the below extension which provides this command to regenerate catalog URLs for the particular product.
Extension :
https://github.com/elgentos/magento2-regenerate-catalog-urls
**Command Syntax : **
php bin/magento regenerate:product:url [-s|--store="..."] [pids1] ... [pidsN]

By this way, You can regenerate Product URL and get rid of the 404 issue.
Thanks!
